# Why won’t 2010 MS Access preview or print a report with subreports?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a perfectly compliled report consisting of two subreports (thanks to the Stack).  I use this line of code to open it:

DoCmd.OpenReport "rptGRANT_REPORT", acViewPreview

…looks like this:

[image]

But when I try to preview or print report it looks like this:  (no subreports):

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This problem originated using the Report Wizard.  I tried another approach by opening a blank report and dragging the subreports into it....**problem solved**.

The vba code for opening and printing the report is the following:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptGRANT_REPORT", acViewReport
```

and

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptGRANT_REPORT", _ 
    acFormatPDF, "C:\Users\User\Downloads\Grant_Report.pdf"
```